# Set datacontext of child UserControl in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am not able to set the datacontext of the UserControl (the UserControl is nested within other UserControl).

I have the below structure:

Views/ViewModels:

```
MainControl <-> MainViewModel <br>
UserControlA <-> ViewModelA<br>
UserControlB <-> ViewModelB<br><br>
ViewModels:<br>
```

`ViewModelB` is a property of `ViewModelA`
MainViewModel instantiates `ViewModelA` and `ViewModelB` in the `ctor`.

Views:
`MainControl` contains `UserControlA`, which in turn contains `UserControlB`
`MainControl` assigns the `ViewModelA` as the datacontext ( This works as expected )

```
<!-- MainControl Xaml-->
<UserControl x:Name="MainControl">

<views:UserControlA DataContext="{Binding ViewModelA}" />

</UserControl>
```

In `UserControlA` i doing the same thing as in the `MainControl` , binding the datacontext
of `UserControlB` to its `ViewModel` which is a property in the `ViewModelA`
This is not working as expected...

```
   <!-- USerControlA Xaml-->
    <UserControl>
    .....
    .....

    <views:UserControlB DataContext="{Binding DataContext.ViewModelB}" /> 

   </UserControl>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the datacontext binding for UserControlB to:

```
<UserControl>
    <views:UserControlB DataContext="{Binding ViewModelB}" /> 
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart , It actually turned out to be a silly misspell on my part with the way I was binding the DataContext. I just finished reading an article on  debugging binding errors which also helped. Here it is [Debugging Binding Errors]http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/debugging/ <br/> I agree with you there is no need for the DataContext.ViewModelB just using ViewModel would suffice in the binding.